# Adding periodical ZFS snapshots as SMF service (svc) in OmnioOS Community Edition

Tags: solaris, zfs, omnios, smf

I'm very much a novice and an amateur when it comes to Solaris-based operating systems, but I've played around with both Solaris and OpenIndiana.  Anyway, I'm currently toying with OmniOS Community Edition, and I have noticed that all the SMF-services for taking periodical ZFS snapshots (eg. hourly, daily, &c) are - as far as I can tell - missing (not just not enabled).  They appear to not be present at the system at all (although I may be wrong).

So is it possible to install/activate (which packet?) ZFS-snapshots for OmniOS - if so, how?

If not, is it possible for me to write my own SMF script(s) (any good tutorials for for how to write SMF scripts in OmniOS)?  [I'm aware I could simply add entries to make snapshots in crontab or associate files, but I'd prefer the SMF route.]